# VS Code : Get Apex Debug Logs : Not getting the latest debug logs

Tags: vs-code

I started using Apex Replay Debbuger last weeks. It was working fine. But suddenly it stopped working as the latest debug logs are not showing you in the VS code. I tried all possiblities of re installling the VS code, turining on apex debugger for debug logs. But no luck. Can you guys help me ? [image]

Comment: Are you sure you're pulling logs from the right org? Pulling logs from the command palette uses whatever org you've set up as the default org in your project.

Comment: It worked for me... I deleted the records from the ApexLog to make it work. We had 5K records in ApexLog. I used dataloader to delete records using query SELECT id FROM ApexLog limit 500. Please try 500 records at a time which is recomemded.. thanks